# jquery : event for textbox enter

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML page.

In this page I have a textbox and three buttons as shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").css("color","green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If I type in "First" in the textbox and enter I want the button with the id "First" to have it's css changed from "green" to "red".

If I type in "First, Second" in the textbox and enter, I want the button with the id "First" & "Second" to have their CSS changed from green to red and so on.

If the input is invalid then do nothing.

I did some research and found that I can modify the css via jquery's .css() method.

But I am not sure as to which event I can use to handle the enter event on textbox.

Can some one help ?

Comment: We have one event which trigger once the input value changed `input` on which you can manipulate the buttons css in it callback function.

Answer (score 0):

In a chnageColor function, you can use **split()** to split the string by **','** and create an array out of it.

Iterate that array using **forEach**  and used the trimmed value of items to select the button and change the color to red.

```js
function changeColor() {
  $("button").css("color","green");
  let valArr = $('#inputid').val().split(',');
  
  valArr.forEach(m => { 
    $('#'+m.trim()).css("color", "red")
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").css("color","green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text"></input>
<button onClick='changeColor();'>Enter</button>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track when enter key is pressed. Here is the example.

```js
$("#inputid").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var inputdata = $(this).val();
        switch(inputdata){
            case "First":
            $("#first").css("color","red");
            break;

            default:
            console.log("do something when input is invalid");
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").css("color","green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").css("color","green");
        $('#inputid').on('keyup',function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 13)
     {
      if($(this).val() == 'First')
      {
       $("#first").css("color","red");
      }
     }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keypress` and check if hit enter using key code 13 check `textbox` contain match your condition with using `indexOf`.

```js
$('#inputid').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if (txt.indexOf('First') != -1) {
      $("#first").css("color", "green");
    }
    if (txt.indexOf('First, Second') != -1) {
      $("#first").css("color", "green");
      $("#second").css("color", "green");
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input> // Type First and enter to see result
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").css("color","green");
$('#inputid').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
  var idArr=$('#inputid').val().split(',');
 $.each(idArr,function(i,v){
  $('#'+v.toLowerCase().trim()).css("color","red");
 })
  }
});  
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you need to use css mehhod.Just use the split function either click event of enter button. or if you want to on enter key , you can use keypress and then detect enter key by keycode 13
Below is the code snippet:-
On keypress:-

```js
$("#inputid").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var val1 = $('#inputid').val();
      if (val1){
      var valArr = $('#inputid').val().split(',');
     
     for (i=0;i<valArr.length;i++){
    $('#'+valArr[i].toLowerCase()).css("color", "red")
      }
      }
      }
     
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").css("color","green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text"></input>
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and onclick event,you can use like below:-

```js
$("#enterBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  $("button").css("color","green");
  var val1 = $('#inputid').val();
  if (val1){
  var valArr = $('#inputid').val().split(',');
 
 for (i=0;i<valArr.length;i++){
$('#'+valArr[i].toLowerCase()).css("color", "red")
  }
  }
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").css("color","green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="inputid" type="text"></input>
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ot1epb7/2/)

```
$(() => {
    $("button").css("color","green");
    $('#inputid').on("input",(e) => {
        $("button").css("color", "green");
        var inputValues = $('#inputid').val().split(",");

         if(inputValues.length){
            inputValues.forEach((item) => {
                 $('#'+item).css("color","red");
            });
         }
    });
})


<input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input>
<br/>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

At first i was thinking "onChange" would be useful for you, but probably what you want it to surround the input in a form, and then use `onSubmit` which will catch that.

There's a page on w3schools covering it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

You'd declare it with something like:

```
<form id="inputform"><input id="inputid" type="text">Enter</input></form>

$('#inputform').onsubmit = function(){ 
   // button colour-change code goes here
};
```